# MYSQL query between two unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How to query data in specific time like: I want to select all records stored between 1 pm and 5 pm during a month , when the time stored in datetime column in Unix timestamp format like so "1403830861".

Comment: Have a look at [Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: @user3462064, sorry I fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function can convert a unix timestamp to a date. The `%k` format (hour represented as an in 0..23) seems to fit the bill nicely. The month could be easily extracted in the same fashion, using the `%m` format and the year using `%Y`. E.g., the following query would return only results from November 2014:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME (timestamp_column, '%k') BETWEEN 13 AND 17 AND
       FROM_UNIXTIME (timestamp_column, '%m') = 11 AND
       FROM_UNIXTIME (timestamp_column, '%Y') = 2014
```

Comment: You have to add one more condition for month user want all record during month